# Is it possible to pass data to one activity but switch to another activity

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2.
I am accepting an Input date from user in first activity and when user presses OK button on the first activity, then displaying a list from which he chooses what he wants to do on the second activity. I need to pass this date to the third activity which will be shown when user chooses an item from the list.

I used **Intent** for connecting the first activity to the second activity containing the list.

How to send data from first to third activity. Is it possible to use multiple intents on same activity ??

Comment: _Is it possible to pass data to one activity but switch to another activity_ Have you tried it?

Comment: Well you can pass from 1st to 2nd , then from 2nd to 3rd.

Comment: but that would be a pile . There got to be abetter solution

Comment: @bub Yes I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.

1. Using intent extra - from activity **A** pass data to activity **B** and same data you can pass to activity **C**
2. Using shared preference - save data to preference and get it from anywhere
3. Using Database - save data to database and use it anywhere
4. Using public static object - init static object and use it anywhere in project

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in various ways.

1. Pass the data from 1st Activity to 2nd Activity. Then from 2nd to 3rd Activity.
2. You can use SharedPreference to store the value in 1st activity and fetch the value in 3rd Activity.

Here's an example for SharedPreference :

```
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "app_data_preference";
pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
editor = pref.edit();


editor.putString(DATE, "Your Date"); //DATE is a string
editor.apply();  //Done. Your date has been saved



//Now to retrieve the data back, use this:

return pref.getString(DATE, "");
```